# Send Mail from Powershell with SSL by default

Tags: powershell, ssl, send

Is it possible to send mail with SSL from Powershell by default? meaning without declaring "UseSsl"

There are this PS scripts that send mail notifications (currently plain text) and would like to find the way to send them encrypted without modifying the scripts.

Is it even possible?
I've been reading similar questions and searching around with no luck

Comment: Not that I'm aware.  Regardless, `-UseSsl` isn't that secure. FYI [Send-MailMessage relies upon SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.2#description) [SmtpClient does not support modern encryption standards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl?view=net-6.0#remarks) [RFC 3207 security considerations](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3207#section-6).  Worth a mention.

Comment: I will take a look to the link, thank you very much. It is not only for the security but also for the deprecation of TLS 10.1 and 1.1.
Currently taking a look over PS profiles which might be just what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing a double relay in the same server with a second SMTP server. So the original one (.local domain) gets the mails as always and sends back to itself to the TLS SMTP server, and from there to 365.
In case it helps anyone else.